# ASP.Net DropDownListFor not showing selected value when padding is added to form-control class

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

As the title suggests, I've got a problem with displaying a drop down list's selected value if there's any modification to the form-control's css's padding values.

This is the current block of code I'm working with:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, 
                               new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"),
                               "", 
                               new { @class = "form-control " })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Genre)
</div>
```

In my Site.css file, I have this:

```
.form-control {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
```

Without the padding added in there, the drop down will display the selected value just fine. However, leaving it in there will select the value but not display it in the drop down box.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the html it spits out when it fails?

Comment: Here's a link to the inspected element.

https://ibb.co/NxTPn2d

Comment: Can't really tell but is it possible the parent element is too small to accommodate all the padding plus the border-radius? Try less padding and see what happens maybe? (Guessing you know your first `option` is empty.)

Comment: I'll give it a go and see what's up. But yes, I was following a tutorial on plural sight, and the first option was empty due to the ' "", ' option in my DropDownListFor parameters. It was supposed to act as a way to show a blank list selection upon the initial load before the user selects something that then gets displayed.

Comment: Looks like you were right. Lowered down the padding to something like 5px 15px and it now displays with the selected value.

Now I just need to figure out how to get the padding on the top and bottom to display. 5px still makes it look like it's too close to the top and bottom border of the drop down just a tad bit but this gets me somewhere.

Thanks for the insight on that!